# Unexpected change of theme after installing flash on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: themes, gui

[image]

Yesterday I installed flash player. Since then my desktop environment/theme has changed completely.

How can I get my previous environment back?

Comment: what are you talking about, exactly? Which part is not what you want?

Comment: every thing has changed. this not what I had earlier. want my regular UI. Even right has stopped working on this UI.

Comment: OK, how was your environment before? How did you install flash? Please [edit] your question to add information

Comment: It looks like Unity 8. Try this: reboot your computer and before entering your password, click on the Ubuntu logo and select Unity instead of Unity 8.

Comment: You were right. I changed it to Unity from unity8. Now it looks good. Got back old default Ubuntu GUI @pomsky

Comment: The flash installation part is a red herring then.

Comment: So how did you change to Unity 8?

Comment: from lock screen